# Finding derivatives w.r.t. initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I've got this problem I can't solve.
I have the differential equation:
$$y'(x, y_0)=y^2(x, y_0)+y(x, y_0)*sin(x)$$
where $y_0$ is the value of $y$ at $x=0$.
I want to find:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial y_0}|_{y_0=0}$$

I think I am on the right track. I have differentiated w.r.t. $y_0$ and I have gotten:
$$u'(x)=(2*y(x,0)+sin(x))*u(x)$$
where:
$$u(x)=\frac{\partial y}{\partial y_0}|_{y_0=0}$$
which would be great (and solvable) if not for the $y(x,0)$ part, which I do not know how to find. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: "$y_0$ is the value" of what "at $x=0$"?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I will edit it, of $y$.

Comment: Since $y_0$ is a constant value, what do you mean by finding the derivative of $y$ with respect to $y_0$?

Comment: @Allawonder Since each initial condition $y(0) = y_0$ gives a unique solution to the differential equation $y' = y^2 + y \sin x$, we can consider the real function of two variables $y(x, y_0)$: the value of the particular solution which has $y(0) = y_0$, evaluated at a specific $x$. Then the partial derivative with respect to $y_0$ is just describing how that function of two variables changes when the initial condition changes.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for the explanation. I think that's clear now. But the notation was overloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Bernoulli equation. Consider
$$
(y^{-1})'=-1-\sin(x)(y^{-1})
$$
which is linear and allows to apply the solution formula for first order linear equations. You are left with some integrals that can not be expressed in elementary functions.

---

Solve the linear DE with integrating factor
$$
(e^{1-\cos x}y(x)^{-1})'=-e^{1-\cos x}\\
e^{1-\cos x}y(x)^{-1}=y_0^{-1}-\int_0^xe^{1-\cos s}ds
$$
to get the solution and its derivative to the initial value
$$
y(x;y_0)=\frac{y_0e^{1-\cos x}}{1-y_0\int_0^xe^{1-\cos s}ds}
\\
\frac{\partial y(x;y_0)}{\partial y_0}=\frac{e^{1-\cos x}}{1-y_0\int_0^xe^{1-\cos s}ds}+\frac{y_0e^{1-\cos x}\int_0^xe^{1-\cos s}ds}{\left(1-y_0\int_0^xe^{1-\cos s}ds\right)^2}
$$
so that finally
$$
\left.\frac{\partial y(x;y_0)}{\partial y_0}\right|_{y_0=0}=e^{1-\cos x}
$$

Comment: Yeah, I know this is a Bernoulli equation. It cannot be solved analytically though. However, what I need to find is $\frac{\partial y}{\partial y_0}|_{y_0=0}$, not the analytic solution itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! How did you find that integrating factor in the very first step though?

Comment: This is just the usual integrating factor for $u'(x)+\sin(x)u(x)=r(x)$, computed as $\exp(\int_0^x\sin(s)ds)$.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$y(x,0)$ is the particular solution to the differential equation with initial value $y_0 = 0$. In other words, it's a function of one variable, say $f(x) = y(x,0)$ satisfying

$$ f'(x) = f^2(x) + f(x) \sin x \\ f(0) = 0 $$

This function is just $f(x) = 0$.

So substituting $y(x,0)=0$, you get

$$ u'(x) = u(x) \sin x $$

Most likely you can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I still don't get why $y(x,0)=0$. I get why $y(0,0)=0$ and I get that it is the solution for $y_0=0$. But why $y(x,0)=0$?

Comment: @NickJackson : Because of the uniqueness theorem. It is a solution of the IVP, thus it is the only one.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!